# Why does Grease Pencil color and stroke move separately when animated?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

I am new to Blender. I painted my first character ever, and once I animated it the color animates separately from my stroke.

Is there a way to fix it so that the color stay within the border?

BEFORE:

[image]

AFTER:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know whether there is a fast workaround, but I am quite certain that you have to manually input the keyframes for the Fill layer, as you did with the Stroke layer.

So just go to the frame you want the color to 'change position' and recolour accordingly.